# Fatal error while extending Catalog Model Layer class - Magento2

Tags: layered-navigation, magento-2.1

Been Working on Layered Navigation for my custom collection which is displayed on a custom page, Have extended the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer`  in my custom class and have added the preference in `di.xml` for the same  `<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" type="Custom\LayeredNav\Model\Layer" />` i need to override just one method i.e `prepareProductCollection()` so i could replace the default collection with the custom collection.

After Following all these steps I have been stucked on the error as below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface

Any guidance would be really helpful. Below is the code.

### Di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" type="Custom\LayeredNav\Model\Layer" />
```

### Custom Layer File

```
<?php 
namespace Custom\LayeredNav\Model;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface;

class Layer  extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $layerStateFactory,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProduct,
            $storeManager,
            $registry,
            $categoryRepository,
            $data
        );

    }


    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);
        //custom collection
        $custom_collection = $this->registry->registry('md_optioncollection');
        //Have set root category id as current category as such the filtered collection is not related to specific category
        $curr_cat_id = $this->registry->registry('current_category')->getId();
        $this->collectionFilter->filter($custom_collection, $curr_cat_id);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

### Custom collection set in my controller file which i store in registry.

```
//this is where i set my custom collection in another file
public function getAttributeCollection()
{
    $attributevalue = $this->getAttributeValue();
        $attr_code = $attributevalue->getAttributeCode();
        $attr_option_value = $attributevalue->getOptionId();
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $store_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store_id');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter($attr_code , ['finset'=>$attr_option_value ])
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility','4')
                   ->setStore($store_id)
                   ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
                   ->setOrder('id', 'DESC');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('md_optioncollection', $collection);
}
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @Marius i have updated my question

Comment: Since you add nothing new to the constructor of your class, what happens if you remove the `__construct` method in your class and delete the contents of the `var/generation` folder?

Comment: @Marius It seems i figured out the error, Actually when i try to instantiate the extended model layer.php object in my module block file either in construct or in the method using the object manager it used to throw that fatal error, but i am unaware of the exact issue still.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Daniel please check below link that might be useful https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135867/layered-navigation-for-custom-collection-on-custom-page-magento2