# Layered navigation for custom collection on custom page - magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation

I am working on fetching layered navigation in magento2 for a custom product collection. I am getting custom collection already on the custom page need to show layered navigation. Tried to adapt [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/57891/40417) magento1 solution but couldn't get far.

Any idea how could i achieve it in magento2. What i have done so far is as below:

> Extended the Catalog ListProduct block for custom product list on my custom page.

```
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{


    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    array $data = [],
    \Custom\LayerNavigation\Model\Layer $testlayerobj
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$postDataHelper,$layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,$urlHelper,$data);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();
        $this->_testlayer = $testlayerobj;
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
          $this->_productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
     }

    public function getLayer()
    {

       $layer = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_layer');
       if ($layer) {
          return $layer;
        }
        return $this->_testlayer;
     }

}
```

> Used the core Search block for layered navigation in layout file

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Search" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalogsearch.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalogsearch.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

> Extended Core layer model to modify the collection.

```
class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
    public function __construct(
      optionStoreFactory  $optionstoreFactory,
      Attrhelper $attrhelper,
      productCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
      AttributevalueFactory $attributevalueFactory,
      CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
      \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
      \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
      \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search\CollectionFilter $filter,
      array $data = []
    ) {
       $this->optionstoreFactory       = $optionstoreFactory;
       $this->attributevalueFactory    = $attributevalueFactory;
       $this->_attrhelper              = $attrhelper;
       $this->request                  = $request;
       $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
       $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->filter = $filter;
       $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $attributevalue = $this->getAttributeValue(); //eg: Manufacturer Attribute details
        $attr_code = $attributevalue->getAttributeCode();
        $attr_option_value = $attributevalue->getOptionId();
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $store_id = $this->request->getParam('store_id');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
               ->addAttributeToFilter($attr_code , ['finset'=>$attr_option_value ])
               ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility','4')
               ->setStore($store_id)
               ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
               ->setOrder('id', 'DESC');
        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->filter->filter($collection, $this->getCurrentCategory());
       return $this;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
       $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
       if ($category) {
           $this->setData('current_category', $category);
       } else {
           $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCurrentStore()->getRootCategoryId());
       $this->setData('current_category', $category);
       }
      return $category;
    }

    public function getCurrentStore()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    }

}
```

As of now i am getting the layer navigation displayed but it ain't specific to my custom collection. As per my debugging the collection is filtered all the way from root category (Which contains whole product catalog) and according to it is fetching the layers.

Comment: Any suggestion would be much appreciated..!

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? If so, please share your answer

Comment: Guys has any of you got any lead on this??

Comment: I was successful to get the layered navigation on custom page for my custom collection... Will need some time to post the solution here as it is very long (Probably in a day or two i will be posting the solution)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to achieve the navigation with below changes, I might not be fully correct with this solution so comments and suggestions are most welcome.

> 1) Prepare di.xml for frontend section as below:

```
<!-- Magento only includes 2 type of layer resolvers i.e Category and search whereas our custom page is neither a category page nor a search page so we need to add a new layer resolver on our custom page-->
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="layersPool" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category</item>
            <item name="search" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</item>
            <item name="customlayer" xsi:type="string">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<!-- To prepare the filterlist for our custom collection which would be passed to the left navigation we need below virtual types for our custom page navigation -->
<virtualType name="customFilterList" type="Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\FilterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
        <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
            <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<!-- once the filter list virtual type is ready we can pass the same to our navigation , I have prepared the virtual type of the core navigation for my custom module and have passed the custom filter list to it -->
<virtualType name="Custom\Navigation\Block\Navigation\Custnavigation" type="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filterList" xsi:type="object">customFilterList</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<!-- As we will be modifying the layer model collection we will need to extend the core model layer, Below virtual type will be required to extend the Catalog model layer else it will throw error for the context in construct method-->
<virtualType name="Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\Context" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Context">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collectionProvider" xsi:type="object">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\ItemCollectionProvider</argument>
        <argument name="stateKey" xsi:type="object">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\StateKey</argument>
        <argument name="collectionFilter" xsi:type="object">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\CollectionFilter</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="context" xsi:type="object">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\Context</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

> 2) Model Layer file: Extend the model layer file with your custom
>   model and modify the collection.

```
namespace Custom\Navigation\Model;
class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{

//Apart from the default construct argument you need to add your model from which your product collection is fetched.

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
    parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $layerStateFactory,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProduct,
            $storeManager,
            $registry,
            $categoryRepository,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {

        /*Unique id is needed so that when product is loaded /filtered in the custom listing page it will be set in the
         $this->_productCollections array with unique key else you will not get the updated or proper collection.
        */

        if (isset($this->_productCollections['some_uinique_id'])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections['some_uinique_id'];
        } else {
            //$collection = Your logic to get your custom collection.
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections['some_unique_id'] = $collection;
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

> 3) I have extended below files as used in di.xml (Have kept the file
>   by just extending have not instantiated the construct method as i
>   didn't required any changes in these file if needed you can modify the
>   specific function in the extended file accordingly), Currently the
>   solution i have applied wasn't able to resolve the category filter
>   issue it still includes the root category filters so had to do a
>   workaround to include the faceteddata (workaround mentioned in 4th
>   point)

```
- Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\FilterList extends
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList



 - Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeList extends
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList



 - Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute extends
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute



 - Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category extends
   \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category (Why catalog
           search is used i have mentioned the same in 4th point)



 - Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\ItemCollectionProvider extends
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider



 - Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\StateKey extends
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\StateKey



 - Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\CollectionFilter extends
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter
```

> 4) Had to do a workaround for category filter in layered navigation as
>   it was not showing option with respect to collection filtered, If any
>   one finds the solution please do update. Below is the code i have used
>   to fix the faceteddata error faced while including the category in my
>   customfilterlist , Due to applying this patch the category option was
>   not displayed in my navigation rest of the filters were appropriate as
>   per my collection.

```
namespace Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer\Filter;

/**
 * Layer category filter
 */
class Category extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category
{
     /**
      * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
      */
    private $escaper;

    /**
     * @var CategoryDataProvider
     */
    private $dataProvider;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
     * @param CategoryManagerFactory $categoryManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\DataProvider\CategoryFactory $categoryDataProviderFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $filterItemFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $layer,
            $itemDataBuilder,
            $escaper,
            $categoryDataProviderFactory,
            $data
        );
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->_requestVar = 'cat';
        $this->dataProvider = $categoryDataProviderFactory->create(['layer' => $this->getLayer()]);
    }

    /**
     * Get data array for building category filter items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();

        $optionsFacetedData = '' ;// $productCollection->getFacetedData('category'); (Here i have set $optionsFacetedData as blank so that category option will not be included in layered navigation)
        $category = $this->dataProvider->getCategory();
        $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

        $collectionSize = $productCollection->getSize();

        if ($category->getIsActive()) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                if ($category->getIsActive()
                    && isset($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()])
                    && $this->isOptionReducesResults($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count'], $collectionSize)
                ) {
                    $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                        $this->escaper->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        $category->getId(),
                        $optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
    }
}
```

> 5) When your custom page is loaded inside your controller execute
>   method you need to set your custom layer which we added in the di.xml
>   along with category and search layer.

```
 - include the below argument in your controller construct method.

     "\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver",

 - inside execute method set your custom layer resolver for your module.

    $this->layerResolver->create('customlayer');
```

> 6) In your layout xml file for the custom page  add below code in
>   body section.

```
<attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>

<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
<!-- below is the virtual type of the core navigation we created -->
    <block class="Custom\Navigation\Block\Navigation\Custnavigation" name="custom.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I am using your code with custom collection in magento 2.1.7. but i am getting blank page.
I think Custom\Navigation\Block\Navigation\Custnavigation is missing in above codes. Can you please give me full code?

Comment: no there is no such block instead i had created a virtual type for it you can check the di.xml code and the code posted here is full code itself.

Comment: Ok can you please send me zip of whole code?

Comment: Sorry cannot send the zip as the above answered code was just a small part of the paid extension we developed.

Comment: m getting error Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on null with line $this->layerResolver->create('customlayer'); 
please help me

Comment: check whether you added $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver; in your construct for the class added in the file constructor. \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver

Comment: My code is as following
protected $layerResolver;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

Comment: public function execute() {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $post_data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $brand_id = $post_data['id'];
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('brand.view');
        $brand_title = $block->getBrandName($brand_id);
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__($brand_title));
        $this->layerResolver->create('customlayer');
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

Comment: But getting error Catalog Layer has been already created

Comment: If i remove $this->layerResolver->create('customlayer'); from execute method i am able to see Layered navigation with wrong filteres and display block of it is Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation

Comment: Any solution for this please?

Comment: Can you please look up at my code? I will send you.

Comment: @Magecode have u resolve your problem?

Comment: Is this solution working fine? Or did anyone find other solution? Because I wasn't able to get it working on my cms page with custom products.

Comment: For customlayer problem, add this to di.xml: <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="layersPool" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="customlayer" xsi:type="string">Custom\Navigation\Model\Layer</item>
      </argument>
   </arguments>
</type>

Answer (score 3):

I successfully applied my custom product collection on the category page's layered navigation and toolbar.

For example, I am fetching the collection of the products with a price of less than 100.

**Step 1:** Add below code snippet

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="custom_product_model_layer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Layer" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_product_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
                <item name="price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
                <item name="decimal" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal</item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create plugin for product collection

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Layer.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Layer
{
  public function aroundGetProductCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
  ) {
    
    $result = $proceed();
    $result->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lt' => 100));
    return $result;
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** Create plugin for toolbar

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Toolbar
{

  protected $_objectManager;
  protected $request;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
  ) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $request
  ) {
    $result = $proceed($request);

    $this->_collection = $request;
    $category = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    if($category)
    {
      $page = $this->request->getParam('p');
      if($page == '')
      {
        $page = 1;
      }
      $this->_collection->getCurPage();
      $this->_collection->setCurPage($page);  
    }
    //else
    //{
    //  $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
    //}
    
    return $result;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hello, I have Used your Code It Updates Product Collection Correclty But it is not updating FIlterList like Category,Price,Attributes and Also count of their Product. Can you Help for this, Its Urgent for me ?? @DineshYadav

Comment: your solution worked perfectly.  I've added some extra bells and whistles to listen for certain categories and then completely rewrite their collection.

Comment: @pixiemedia You can upvote my answer if it worked for you ☺️

Comment: i already have ;) did find a small issue by the way - in the plugin code, the final part after the last else breaks search results.  comment that bit out

Comment: stopped working on M2.2 - sql error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'field list' - working out the solution

Comment: @pixiemedia, did you able to fix the unknown column issue? If yes please post your solution.

Comment: hi, sorry havent got around to it yet - I can tell you the issue is specifically with the price filter though - disable the price filter on the collection and it renders fine

Comment: filter attributes are not showing in sidebar. can you tell me how to add filter attributes  in sidebar

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get layered navigation mostly working for a custom product collection on a custom page. I uploaded the source code for my module [here](https://notabug.org/rtownley/Magento_2_Module_Custom_CMS_Page_with_Layered_Navigation). The only problems are that the Price filter doesn't display the correct product counts. Because of this, I modified the layered navigation view to hide the Price filter. But because I used a custom view file, for some reason the filters in the sidebar can't be collapsed anymore.

If anyone can fix that issue, feel free to make a pull request. I'm also trying to figure out how to implement this for a CMS page created through the Magento 2 backend, instead of for a page created manually through xml.