# Magento 2: How to setup layerd navigation in custom product collection?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, collection, cms-pages

I am trying to set a layered navigation filter on the custom cms page.
for that, I have created a 1 cms page name test with **two-column with left bar.**
and inside it, I have called one template file

> {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
>   template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}

**in the CMS layout update, I have placed this code**

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**for calling product filter**

**inside the test.phtml file I have searched the products from the collection.**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["test"])) {
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
        $imageHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $collection = $productCollection->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('test', $_REQUEST["test"])                
                        ->load();
    }
```

when I click on any of the filter options then my URL becomes

> http://127.0.0.1/test?price=-1000&test=code

so can I get the filter request but it is a very tedious task to set a filter in collection manually.

**And on the home page, I have set one search box for search products.**

```
    <form id="testsearch" action="http://127.0.0.1/magento/test" >
        <div>Find Matching Part</div>
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="test">
        <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

> I know that this is not a standard way to do that but anyone can help
>   me to set this filter in custom cms page.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

**Thanks in advance..!**

Comment: I think it's easier if we build a custom router, create custom layout and template. Using cms page is hard in this case.

Comment: thank you @KhoaTruongDinh can you help me to set a product filter here..

Comment: You get some reference from here : https://notabug.org/rtownley/Magento_2_Module_Custom_CMS_Page_with_Layered_Navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use this code to resolve my issue.

```
   $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
   $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
   $collection = $productCollection->create()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

                if (@$_REQUEST["cat"]) {
                    $category = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load(@$_REQUEST["cat"]);
                    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
                }if (@$_REQUEST["attr_code_1"]) {
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('attr_code_1', @$_REQUEST["attr_code_1"]);     
                }if (@$_REQUEST["attr_code_2"]) {
                    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attr_code_2', @$_REQUEST["attr_code_2"]);
                }if (@$_REQUEST["attr_code_3"]) {
                    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attr_code_3', @$_REQUEST["attr_code_3"]);
                }

                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('test', @$_REQUEST["@$_REQUEST["test"]"]);    
                $collection->load();
```

I also know that it is not the right way to do this but it works for me to resolve my issue.

If anyone have a better answer then provide here...
the boundary is not closed...

Answer (score 1):

Go with all below mentioned solutions/post, some of them will definitely help you.

[Layered navigation for custom collection on custom page - magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/135867/81151)

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-layered-navigation-on-custom-page-in-magento-2/

https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/custom-product-collection-layered-navigation-magento-2.html

http://www.techytalk.info/adding-layered-navigation-custom-controller-action-magento/