# Can we use virtualType in programmatically in layererd navigation filter?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, magento2.2.6

Just wanted to know, how can we use virtualType programmatically in magento 2 custom script file ?

Actually I am building api for layered navigation and I am getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in /var/www/html/eoutlet/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/eoutlet/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Catalog...', Array) #1 /var/www/html/eoutlet/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Catalog...') #2 /var/www/html/eoutlet/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Catalog...') #3 /var/www/html/eoutlet/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Amasty\\Shopby\\M...') #4 /var/www/html/eoutl in /var/www/html/eoutlet/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

FYI - I am using amasty shopby extension and found that, it is using virtualType in di.xml file.

```
<virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\FilterList">
 <arguments>
        <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
            <item name="price" xsi:type="string">Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
            <item name="decimal" xsi:type="string">Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal</item>
            <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="place" xsi:type="string">sidebar</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

I am implementing following code to get the result, but getting above error

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$filterableAttributes = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList'::class);
$filterTypes = [
            'attribute'=>\Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute::class,
            'category'=>\Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Category::class,
            'decimal'=>\Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal::class,
            'price'=>\Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\Filter\Price::class
        ];

$layerResolver = $objectManager->get('\Amasty\Shopby\Model\Resolver'::class);
$filterList = $objectManager->get(
'\Amasty\Shopby\Model\Layer\FilterList'::class,
    [
       'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes,
       'filters'=>$filterTypes                   
    ]
);
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, we can create

Comment: How ? Can you please give an example, so that I could understand ?

Comment: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135867/layered-navigation-for-custom-collection-on-custom-page-magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135867/layered-navigation-for-custom-collection-on-custom-page-magento2)

Comment: Programmatically, How can I add virtural type arguments ?

Comment: I think, You are not understanding my concern.