# Magento2.3.3: Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'field list'

Tags: custom, layered-navigation, magento2.3.3

Working on custom layered navigation on custom collection. follow this solution [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135867/layered-navigation-for-custom-collection-on-custom-page-magento2)

Getting an Error:

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'field list', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id), ROUND(MAX(e.min_price ) * 1, 2) AS `max`, ROUND(MIN(e.min_price ) * 1, 2) AS `min`, STDDEV_SAMP(ROUND((e.min_price ) * 1, 2)) AS `std` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_brands` ON (`at_brands`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_brands`.`attribute_id` = '509') AND (`at_brands`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (FIND_IN_SET('16304', at_brands.value)) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set 0 in is_filterable column for attribute price in catalog_eav_attribute table