# Magento 2 : BreadCrumbs and Page Title not Display on Custom Page

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, breadcrumbs

I used this blog for add custom collection on my custom page with layered navigation. But, there are not display breadcrumbs and page title using this below blog.

How to add it?

[image]

> https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-layered-navigation-on-custom-page-in-magento-2/

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal It's also not display swatch in configurable product.

Comment: @AmitBera Can you please help me?

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal any update for help?

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code in you xml or

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">home</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">myaccount</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Custom Page</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Custom Page</item>
                <item name="last" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

If you have created cms PAge then u can add it in  "Layout Update XML" field or u can use below settings for enable breadcrumb in ur cms page set it as yes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. But, It should be display dynamic.

Comment: I have updated my answer plz check if it works for u.

Comment: It's custom page.

Comment: Do you know any other way to display custom product collection with applied filter? same as like category page with layered navigation.

Comment: Do you want with applied filter or with layered navigation ?

Comment: I want product collection with filter. For ex. http://example.com/black.html . If i execute this URL then, all black attribute option products should be display in page. Layout should be same as like category page.

Comment: I also use this answer. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195705
But, in this siderbar items not update.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Yes I have created it for FreshDeals so if customer open url like example.com/freshdeal I am display all products of freshdeals , will it work for you?

Comment: Yes. I want to do same as like this. Can you please share your module as answer or github link to download. So, I can check it?

Comment: okay sure give me a moment please.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm waiting.

Comment: I am commiting it in git and will provide u git link in sometime

Comment: Okay. @Hitesh :)

Comment: are you available?

Comment: Hello Sorry for delay in response I have added code in git below is code link https://github.com/hiteshagrawal84/featuredproducts, Hope it helps you , if so could you please add vote for us and accept the answer

Comment: No issue. Can you please provide me link?

Comment: Sure. Let me check that.

Comment: Hi. Can you please open automatically chat discussion? I can't able to click. I set your module. It's return error. Call to a member function setProductCollection() on boolean in /var/www/html/mn233/app/code/DP/FeaturedProducts/Controller/Index/Index.php:68 Can you please tell me? how to solve it?

Comment: I solved this above error issue. in layout file, change template file : Magento_Catalog:product/list.phtml . But, layout something wrong. It's not seems like category page.

Comment: yes u need to make some changes , what issue u r facing?

Comment: Configurable's simple product not display in collection and page layout seems incorrect. I added screenshot in question. Please help me hitesh. It's imp for me. I'm stuck in that.

Comment: sorry but with the image it's difficult to understand, why you want to display simple product for configurable products?

Comment: Okay. But, Layout is not correct. Can you please help me to solve it? I upvoted answer. I will accept soon after layout looks like category page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107538/discussion-between-daniel-philip-and-hitesh-agrawal).